# Cloudant couchdb changes api and geospatial indexes

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Currently I'm doing filtered replication by monitoring the below resource:

`_changes?filter=_selector&include_docs=true&attachments=true&limit=20`

As you can see, I'm using a selector defined by

```
"selector": {
  "type": "Property"
}
```

and everything is working great. Now I need to add another criteria which is geospatial index. I want to replicate documents with locations in a radius. e.g.
lat=-11.05987446&lon=12.28339928&radius=100
How can I replicate using the above filtered replication technique and replicate documents within a radius?
Thanks

Comment: If you go on cloudant, you have some query options for your geospatial index. Change them as you wish and click on **API** at the top right to get the URL settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selector` filter for `_changes` is not backed by an index - it just uses the same syntax as [Query selectors](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/find.html#find-selectors), which currently does not support geospatial operations.

I think you have 3 options:

#### 1. Use a bounding box

Your selector would then look something like:

```
"selector": {
  "type": "Property",
  "lat": {
    "$gt": -11
  },
  "lat": {
    "$lt": 11
  },
  "lon": {
    "$gt": 12
  },
  "lon": {
    "$lt": 14
  }
}
```

Perhaps you could then further restrict the results on the client if you need exactly a radial search.

#### 2. Implement a radius search in a JavaScript filter

This means dropping the use of the `selector, would be relatively slow (anything that involves JavaScript in Couch/Cloudant will be) but gives you exactly the result you want.

#### 3. Run a query and replicate the resulting ids

Use a [search](https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html#geographical-searches) or [geospatial](https://docs.cloudant.com/geo.html) query to get the set of _ids you need and use a `doc_id` based replication to fetch them.

Lastly, it's worth considering whether you really want replication (which implies the ability for documents to sync both ways) or if you're just caching / copying data to the client. Replication carries some overhead beyond just copying the data (it needs to figure out the delta between the client and server, retrieve the rev history for each doc, etc) so, if you don't need to write the docs back to the server, maybe you don't need it.

If you do go down the replication route, you may need to handle cases where documents that you previously replicated no longer match the query so updates do not propagate in subsequent replications.

If not, you may be better off just running a query with `include_docs=true` and manually inserting the documents to a local database.

Comment: For the time being, the requirements just demand one sided i.e. server to client replication. Since I'm not using the _replicator end-point I would assume I'm not getting the overhead you talked about above in case of `two-way replication` or `sync` ?

Comment: correct - it depends what you do with the `_changes` result. If it's not a client-side replicator (PouchDB etc) then you don't have the overhead. However, it is likely more efficient to use an index instead of a runtime iteration over `_changes` (effectively what a filter does) if you just need to fetch the docs which match a query. If you're worried about transferring docs that you already have, perhaps do it in 2 steps - 1 to fetch ids from the query and another which fetches the docs by key using `_all_docs`.

Comment: `The selector filter for _changes is not backed by an index - it just uses the same syntax as Query selectors, which currently does not support geospatial operations.` Does that mean the selectors do not utitlize my query based indexes which I have put in design docs?

Answer (score 1):

The _selector filter for the changes feed isn't backed by an index, it's basically a handy shortcut to achieve the same thing as a javascript filter, but much faster as it's executed directly in the Erlang.

As it's not index-backed, you can't tap into a geo-index that way.

You'd be better off to run either a bounding box or radius query to get the ids and then fetch those documents with a bulk_get or with a post to all_docs with the ids in the body.

https://cloudant.com/wp-content/uploads/Cloudant-Geospatial-technical-overview.pdf